# Alter environment after a command

Tags: linux, bash

Altering the environment just for a single command is very simple:

```
DB=postgresql some_command --with --arguments
```

Unfortunately, I have to do this on a remote server and due to limitations of the deployment, I can only edit what comes *after* the some_command. The following would be nice, but doesn't do the trick (in Bash):

```
some_command --with --arguments DB=postgresql
```

Is there some other Bash hack to get there?

Comment: What are your constraints?  Specifically, what are the constraints that mean you can't use the first version above?

Comment: The "some_command" is "bundle install" in my case. I have only one config option to pass arbitrary arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another idea, a bit wild I'm afraid:

```
some_command --do-nothing `DB=postgresql some_command --now-really`
```

The idea is that the backquoted command will actually do what you want. The first `some_command` is only there so the command will start as you want it. You should find parameters that would make it do something harmless.

If you have nothing equivalent for the `--do-nothing` parameter, you can do this:

```
some_command `DB=postgresql some_command --now-really; ps-grep-kill`
```

Where `ps-grep-kill` is a combination of these commands (I leave the details as an exercise), which finds the parent process, which is just about to run `some_command`, and kills it before it gets a chance to (but after the backquoted `some_command` has run already).

Comment: Clever workaround! Unfortunately, my "some_command" is "bundle install" which doesn't have no argument anywhere close to --do-nothing.

Comment: OK, I'm adding a workaround for that. But it gets even uglier.

Comment: The ps-grep-kill approach is interesting, but too hacky for me. However, the first solution can come in handy, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you just run the command, it can't change the environment.
But if you source it, it can:
`source some_command --with --arguments DB=postgresq`
Shorthand:
`. some_command --with --arguments DB=postgresql`

I prefer not to source large scripts this way, because then they may end up changing more than you intended. So I'd write two scripts - one finds what you want to change, and outputs it. The other is a very small one, that runs the first one (normally, without `source`) and does the changes.

But re-reading your question, it seems like you can't use `source`. So I see no way to do what you want.

Comment: If you don't want it to change the environment, use a sub-shell: `(source some_command ...)`.

Comment: I think neither a subshell nor my answer are actually useful here. He wants something that starts with `some_command`, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Can you execute `export DB=postgresql` to modify the environmental variables globally?  Then you can run subsequent commands that pick up the new environmental variable.

Comment: Obviously, but that's just it: No way I can do that.